# Outlook 2010 Cant't Read Encrypted Email, But Send

Tags: encryption, microsoft-outlook-2010

I upgraded my desktop from Outlook 2007 to Outlook 2010. Now I can't read encrypted emails; they appear as a blank body. I tried every help in the internet, but most of them point you to your S/Mime settings. But they seem all to be fine, since I can encrypt and sign emails properly. The basic key handling in the OS works fine, since I can read my encrypted email in OWA with the IE-Plugin.

I don't know where to start looking, can anyone help?

Comment: Why does the title mention Outlook 2012 but the question mention Outlook 2010?  Did you migrate the Outlook settings or simply recreate them?

Comment: I migrated the settings. But since then I removed and added the S/Mime settings.